# Mongodb: How to find and remove a string from a comma separated string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a field called groups with comma separated strings (i.e.) groups:1,2,6,8 like that.
Now I want to remove the 6 from that field and update and my output should be like groups:1,2,8.
As I'm new to mongodb, i tried and can't find the process to find and update the comma separated string within a field.

```
db.collection.find({ "groups": { "$regex": "6" } })
```

find 6 and remove it and need to update as 1,2,8 in the field "groups"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation to update. This workaround removes the unwanted ","

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  
  {
    $project: {
      key: {
        $filter: {
          input: { $split: [ "$key","," ] },
          cond: { $ne: ["$$this", "3" ]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      key: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$key",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $concat: [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$cond": [{"$eq": ["$$value", ""]}, "", ", " ]
              },
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oa0r825QMKL)**

Comment: For specific id, should I update like this db.collection.update({_id:3},

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly you can use [`$replaceAll`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceAll/) in this way:

- Using `$match` to filter by document you want to update
- `$set` the value group with the new data replacing desired value by white space.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {"group": {"$regex": "6"}}
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "group": {
        "$replaceAll": {
          "input": "$group",
          "find": "6",
          "replacement": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GfdBDawAS7K)